# MOUSEBUTTONDOWN event not responding [pygame]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm not able to detect the event when ***Mouse button*** is **pressed down**.

Before asking this question I've tried:

```py
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1260, 960))
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG")

finish = False
fps = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                print('MOUSE BUTTON PRESSED DOWN')
    clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.update()
```

What's wrong with the code?

Also, I'm not getting any errors in my terminal.

Comment: it seems you coded to make the check for MOUSEBUTTONDOWN only happen if - at the same time - you have an event KEYDOWN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html).

```
QUIT              none
ACTIVEEVENT       gain, state
KEYDOWN           key, mod, unicode, scancode
KEYUP             key, mod
MOUSEMOTION       pos, rel, buttons
MOUSEBUTTONUP     pos, button
MOUSEBUTTONDOWN   pos, button
JOYAXISMOTION     joy (deprecated), instance_id, axis, value
JOYBALLMOTION     joy (deprecated), instance_id, ball, rel
JOYHATMOTION      joy (deprecated), instance_id, hat, value
JOYBUTTONUP       joy (deprecated), instance_id, button
JOYBUTTONDOWN     joy (deprecated), instance_id, button
VIDEORESIZE       size, w, h
VIDEOEXPOSE       none
USEREVENT         code
```

You're looking for the `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` event, not `KEYDOWN`:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    ...
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print('MOUSE BUTTON PRESSED DOWN')
```

Answer (score 0):

`MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` is not a keydown event

This should work

```py
import pygame, sys
pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1260, 960))
pygame.display.set_caption("PONG")

finish = False
fps = 60

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not finish:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        
        if event.key == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            print('MOUSE BUTTON PRESSED DOWN')
    clock.tick(fps)
    pygame.display.update()
```